# Not planned in rou.xml vehicles occur in SUMO while using veins

Tags: omnet++

I am using **veins 3.0**, with **sumo0.21.0** and **omnetpp4.4**.
In the *name.rou.xml* I defined some vehicle types like this:

```
<vType id="vtype0" accel="2.6" decel="6.6" sigma="0.5" length="2.5"  minGap="2.5" speedFactor="0.8" speedDev="0"  maxSpeed="88" color="1,1,0"/>
```

I also defined flows:

```
   <flow id="flow0" type="vtype6" route="B470" begin="0"  end="21599" period="3600"/>
   <flow id="flow1" type="vtype6" route="B470" begin="15"  end="604800" period="604800"/>
   <flow id="flow2" type="vtype6" route="B470" begin="30"  end="604800" period="604800"/>
   <flow id="flow3" type="vtype6" route="B470" begin="45"  end="604800" period="604800"/>
   <flow id="flow4" type="vtype6" route="B470" begin="60"  end="604800" period="604800"/>
   <flow id="flow5" type="vtype6" route="B470" begin="75"  end="604800" period="604800"/>
   <flow id="flow6" type="vtype6" route="B470" begin="90"  end="604800" period="604800"/>
   <flow id="flow7" type="vtype6" route="B470" begin="105"  end="604800" period="604800"/>
   <flow id="flow8" type="vtype6" route="B470" begin="120"  end="604800" period="604800"/>
   <flow id="flow9" type="vtype6" route="B470" begin="125"  end="604800" period="604800"/>
   <flow id="flow10" type="vtype6" route="B470" begin="130"  end="604800" period="604800"/>
   <flow id="flow11" type="vtype6" route="B470" begin="135"  end="604800" period="604800"/>
   <flow id="flow12" type="vtype6" route="B470" begin="140"  end="604800" period="604800"/>
   <flow id="flow13" type="vtype6" route="B470" begin="145"  end="899" period="15"/>
   <flow id="flow14" type="vtype6" route="B470" begin="900"  end="21599" period="3600"/>
   <flow id="flow15" type="vtype6" route="B470" begin="2700" end="21599" period="3600"/>
```

In a normal case the vehicles shall appear in SUMO, according to the flows defined. The problem is that in my simulation vehicles appear spontaneously beginning with second *1014*.
I get the id of vehicles with `nodeId = mobility->getExternalId();`. Normally id is looking like `flow13.4`. When not planned vehicles occur their id is looking like `vtype0_1`. So SUMO just chooses some *vType* from my definitions and starts it. In this way about 1000 new vehicles are added to my simulation. Why is this happening? Does anybody know, in what cases SUMO starts a vehicle, apart from defining a flow? 
The occurrence of vehicles:

```
flow13.49 at 880
flow14.0 at 900
vtype4_0 at 1014
vtype2_1 at 1027
vtype4_2 at 1045
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have set the [numVehicles](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-3.0/src/modules/mobility/traci/TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd.ned#L59) parameter, which instructs Veins to instantiate random vehicles whenever less than the configured number is present in your simulation.

Comment: But this vehicles always appear if there is no more vehicle in simulation. It seems that veins or sumo is trying to have at least one vehicle on the road.

Comment: That sounds odd. Did you change anything in the source code? If not, do you have a minimal example you can share?

Comment: Currently the unplanned vehicles are no more appearing

Comment: Glad to hear that! Let me know if you can reproduce the problem and I'll be happy to investigate.